# ERROR en la transformación de un EXISTS en JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subconsultas, exists

Estoy realizando la transformación de una query y llevar todas las tablas al FROM para darle performance pero surge un error **"identificador no valido"**.
Abajo le muestro el paso a paso de como transformo una query que tiene un EXISTS en un JOIN. La query del **Paso 1** ejecuta normalmente pero la query del **Paso 3** arroja ese error. ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal en la transformación?
**Paso 1**: Esta es la query original

```
  --PASO 1
  SELECT     *
  FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd o 
  WHERE       EXISTS (SELECT      1
                      FROM        obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                      WHERE       oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT      og.oga_id
                                                    FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                                    WHERE       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                                    AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo) 
                      AND         oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
                      AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
                      AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo);
```

**Paso 2**: transformar el EXISTS en IN

```
  SELECT     *
  FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd o 
  WHERE     (o.obn_objeto_id, o.obn_tipo_objeto_id, o.obn_periodo) IN(SELECT      oo.obn_objeto_id, oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id, oo.obn_periodo 
                                                                        FROM        obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                                                                        WHERE       oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT      og.oga_id
                                                                                                      FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                                                                                      WHERE       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                                                                                      AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo)
```

**Paso 3**: transformar el IN en un JOIN pero acá surge el error IDENFICADOR NO VALIDO en el identificador **o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID** y **o.obn_periodo**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   WHERE og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
    AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  SELECT     *
  FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd o
  JOIN       (SELECT      oo.obn_objeto_id, oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id, oo.obn_periodo 
              FROM        obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
              WHERE       oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT      og.oga_id
                                            FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                            WHERE       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID --ERROR ACA..!
                                            AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo --ERROR ACA..!))
   ON(o.obn_objeto_id=oo.obn_objeto_id AND
      o.obn_tipo_objeto_id=  oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id AND
      o.obn_periodo oo.obn_periodo );
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo sin subconsultas, y así quitar el `IN( SELECT ` que también afecta el desempeño: `SELECT * FROM obligaciones@dbl_cldd o INNER JOIN obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo ON ... INNER JOIN obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og ON ...`

Comment: Es decir en vez de tener una query con subconsulta escalonado ejemplo ```SELECT * FROM tablaA JOIN ( SELECT * FROM tablaB on .... JOIN (SELECT * FROM tablaC))``` es hacerlo secuencial los JOINS? Ejemplo ```SELECT * FROM tablaA JOIN tablaB on.... JOIN tablaC on...```

Comment: ¿Por qué crees que mover las tablas a la consulta principal generará una mejora de rendimiento? Hacerlo así normalmente resulta en lo contrario puesto que EXISTS es muy eficiente.

Comment: En ese punto estásm fuera del contexto de la tabla con alias o.

Comment: Vas  a  tener que hacer primaramente un el SELECT oo IN como un todo con un WITH previo logicamente sin el WHERE y luego hacer referencia a este WITH  en el JOIN con o incluyendo el WHERE

Comment: ...luego hacer referencia a este WITH en el JOIN con "o" incluyendo el WHERE

Comment: @LuisCazares por que me explicaron en la clase de tuning que llevar las tablas en el FROM es mas eficiente que colocarlo en el WHERE. AL estar en el Where cuando se ejecute la consulta esa sub consulta se ejecutara N veces tenga registro la tabla exterior.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich siiiiii esa manera puedo hacerlo primero hacer que traigo la tabla con el WITH y luego referenciarla. la voy a chekar...!!! por q plantie este problema por q tengo una query q trae 1 billon de registros y tarda un montonazo de tiempo. Habia aplicado el WITH a la query y redujo el tiempo pero ahora queria poner todo las tablas en el FROM con el WITH pero no salio por que no lo acomode como me decis..! lo voy a intentar cualquier cosa tiro de nuevo un mensaje por aca

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich lo que planteo el usuario Sal (1er comentario) es posible transformar una query que tiene subconsulta escalonada en una query EQUIVALENTE haciendo desaparecer las subconsultas con JOIN???????????????

Comment: Cuando el tema es *tuning* los índices son muy relevantes; nos ayudaría conocerlos.

Comment: Si, ahora bien debería  ir de frente al join con la tabla obligaciones genericas y poner las condiciones de where in el ON del join obigaciones con obligacionesgenericas

Comment: Deberia se SELECT * FROM obligaciones o JOIN obligacionesgenericas og ON (o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID=og.oga_icp_ipo_id  AND         o.obn_periodo = og.oga_periodo)

Comment: Perdon tienes que incluir  la condición o.obn_oga_id =  og.oga_id en el ON

Comment: @LuisCazares te puedo compartir el codigo para que me recomiendes donde puedo encarar ?

Comment: pasar de un EXISTS a un JOIN no necesariamente gana en desempeño ni es equivalente, ya que depende de los datos y de los posibles índices

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es debido a que una tabla derivada (o subconsulta en el from) no puede hacer referencia a otras tablas cuando se usa un JOIN. Dependiendo de la versión que manejes, puedes usar `APPLY` para poder referenciar columnas externas.

```
  SELECT     *
  FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd o
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT      oo.obn_objeto_id, oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id, oo.obn_periodo 
              FROM        obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
              WHERE       o.obn_objeto_id=oo.obn_objeto_id AND
                          o.obn_tipo_objeto_id=  oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id AND
                          o.obn_periodo = oo.obn_periodo AND
                          oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT      og.oga_id
                                            FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                            WHERE       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                            AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo ))x;
```

Sin embargo, el problema que quieres evitar, tal vez persista puesto que `APPLY` por lo general resulta en un `JOIN` de tipo `nested loops` que precisamente repite la consulta las veces que sea necesaria.

Para convertirlo en JOIN, necesitas cambiar la tabla derivada y usar directamente la tabla real.

```
SELECT     *
FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd o
JOIN       obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo  ON o.obn_objeto_id=oo.obn_objeto_id AND
                                        o.obn_tipo_objeto_id=  oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id AND
                                        o.obn_periodo = oo.obn_periodo
WHERE     oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT      og.oga_id
                            FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                            WHERE       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID
                            AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo );
```

Sin embargo, estos dos métodos pueden traer un exceso de filas debido a que la relación seguramente no es 1 a 1. En eso es mucho más eficiente el EXISTS, ya que solo valida existencia y no require regresar filas a la consulta.

Quien haya dicho que un JOIN es más eficiente que un EXISTS no debería de estar dando clases de tuning. Quien asegure que EXISTS siempre será mejor, tampoco debería de dar clases. Lo importante es ver que ambos resultados sean correctos y examinar los planes de ejecución (usando EXPLAIN PLAN), lecturas y tiempos entre las alternativas que entreguen el mismo resultado en cualquier situación.

Comment: Hola Luis gracias por tu respuesta. El problema que tengo que esta query demora un monton de tiempo y lo pude reducir a 200 min usando WITH. Saber si tiene INDICES o ver el EXPLAIN PLAN no puedo verlo ya que el DBA no nos otorga los privilegios necesario ¿por que? No lo se, eso es un tema de burocracia de ellos. Por tanto mi trabajo es recibir la query y darle la perfomance lo mejor posible para reducir el tiempo de ejecucion para luego se convierta en un JOB.

Comment: Si el EXISTS es la mejor para que esta query funcione es dejarla asi no mas y buscar otras alternativas. Ahora estoy investigando que puedo llegar hacer con un row_num, rank, dense_rank

Comment: Si el DBA no permite que se vea el EXPLAIN PLAN en desarrollo, esa compañía debe buscar otro DBA. Otra opción es trabajar con el DBA para pedir que él genere el plan y se pueda analizar. Si no te dan las herramientas para trabajar correctamente, lo único que podrás hacer es disparar a ciegas.

Comment: Por cierto, si reducir el tiempo a 200 minutos es un avance, el problema no es la consulta.

Comment: si estoy muy a ciegas jaja es lo q tengo. Ahora tire la consulta con los cambios realizado y esperando un buen tiempo de respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Es cierto que todo `SELECT` después de un `WHERE` disminuye el desempeño, es mejor usar `JOIN` (en el `FROM`); sin embargo, si no se tienen -y usan- los índices adecuados el resultado puede ser contraproducente.

Por lo anterior, y con la reserva de conocer tus índices y un `EXPLAIN PLAN`, la consulta puede quedar así:

```
SELECT *
  FROM obligaciones@dbl_cldd o 
    INNER JOIN obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
      ON    oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
        AND oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
        AND oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo
    INNER JOIN obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
      ON    og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
        AND og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
  WHERE og.oga_id = oo.obn_oga_id
```

Comment: Hola Sal, gracias por tu respuesta. Te cuento que el DBA no nos otorga muchos privilegios a tal punto que no podemos saber si hay INDICES o al menos saber el EXPLAIN PLAN. y mucho no podemos hacer. Nos entregan la query y es tratar de dar la mejor perfomance posible y bajar el tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: De la query original que tardaba michisimo tiempo y reducirla a 200 min con WITH fue un gran avance. Ahora con el curso que estoy haciendo de TUNING y con la transformación de subconsulta a JOIN que me explicaste voy a lanzar la query de nuevo a ver si puedo reducir el tiempo un poco mas. Gracias...!